# Swift: UICollectionView dynamic cells size in a 2 column grid based on odd or even no of items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a collection view where I have to load images from the API data. Challenge here is that my collection view is a 2 column grid and if the number of images are odd, then the first cell should span to full  row. Here is the design mock up I want

[image: design mockup]

So as per the mockup

- If items are even, then display them 2 in each row.
- If items are odd, display the first one to span the full row, and show the remaining spanning 2
  in each row.

I am following this tutorial to create grid view but don't know how to achieve the designs in mockup

https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could override `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`. By checking it the numbers of totals items is odd or not, and decide of the size accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Larme, thanks for prompt reply. I have a confustion here. If I override sizeForItemAt by checking the number of totals items is odd or not, wouldn't that apply to all cells?

Can you demonstrate it by providing sample code? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: In pseudo code, use modulo to know if it's odd or not:  `if isOdd && indexPath.row == 0 { return bigSize } else return smallSize`, where `smallSize` and `bigSize` are `CGSize` calculated according to the width you want (and potentially the inter space, padding, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check the number of items that you have and set the sizes depending if is odd or not. If it is odd and you want only the first item in each three to be of bigger size you can also check for the remainder by dividing by 3. Here is the example.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) % 2 == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 5) / 2, height: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 5) / 2)
    }
    let remaider = (Double(indexPath.item)/3).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
    if remaider == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width, height:  self.collectionView.frame.size.width)
    }
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 5) / 2, height: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 5) / 2)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I don't want first item in each three to be of bigger size. Its just the first item if items are odd. I had to modify your answer a little bit to work.
`if collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) % 2 != 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.width)
        }
        
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 5) / 2, height: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 5) / 2)`